# ANCM: Inprocess: 500 error after switching to inprocess from outofprocess mode

Tags: .net-core

When I publish or deploy dotnetcore api's on server it can show the ANCM: Inprocess: 500 Error. when i am switching to outofprocess from inprocess it worked fined. what is the Issue

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, but If I have time today I'll look for you and post an actual answer, but no promises.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Is the .net core 2.2 present on the server?

Comment: Is it just one application, or multiple apps? In case of multiple apps (on virtual directories) - you need to keep same hosting model in all apps. https://devsdaily.com/http-error-500-ancm-in-process-handler-load-failure/